# order by with operation on select case query

Tags: postgresql

I want to rank a table by multi-columns and sum of each point that is decided by value.

For example, I can get some columns and each points by below query.

```
select 
      (case when seller=true then 50 else 0 end) as sel, 
      (case when buyer=true then 40 else 0 end) as buy 
from company;
```

but I can't order by this values by like this query

```
select 
      (case when seller=true then 50 else 0 end) as sel, 
      (case when buyer=true then 40 else 0 end) as buy 
from company 
order by (sel + by);
```

or this

```
select 
      (case when seller=true then 50 else 0 end) as sel, 
      (case when buyer=true then 40 else 0 end) as buy,
      (sell, buy) as sm
from company
order by sm;
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Oh, sorry, I found the answer.

```
select * from 
    (select 
        (case when seller=true then 50 else 0 end) as sel, 
        (case when buyer=true then 40 else 0 end) as buy 
    from company) as tmp 
order by (tmp.sel + tmp.buy);
```